# APIs or databases that allows one to retrieve the works that a book cites

Tags: citations

Are there APIs or databases that allow to retrieve the works that a *book* cites. Eg. I give it an ISBN, and it returns all the works that it cites (*not* those it is cited by).

APIs or databases like Microsoft Academic Search usually only contain citations of journal articles and papers, but not books.

Answer (score 3):

Mendeley has quite powerful database on all kind of sources.

http://dev.mendeley.com/

---

Also, you should check Elsevier's developer portal, as they provide a number of APIs for their services:

http://dev.elsevier.com/

Where ScienceDirect API is especially relevant for you:
http://www.elsevier.com/solutions/sciencedirect/support/api

As you probably know, Elsevier is one of (if not the) the biggest publisher(s) of academic publications, including books.

In case you might want to query your own instance of Mendeley Desktop - check my blog post, for few starting points:

http://blog.veles.rs/mendeley-desktop-http-api/

---

Answer (score 1):

Books (and their chapters) may have a DOI, especially if their publishers focus on academic works.

Use the DOI to access *CrossRef*'s [API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) (by using `https://api.crossref.org/works/{DOI}`) and look for the `reference`-field.

You could even access the API by the ISBN via `http://api.crossref.org/types/book/works?filter=isbn:{ISBN}` (though it seems to me that the API usually works better with DOIs).

[Here is an example](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1017/9781108677516) from a book published by Cambridge University Press. It says `reference-count: 1427` and lists all the 1427 works cited by that book.